# Finding a class by dynamic id and accessing the data value

Tags: jquery

I have tree structured data where I want to get the id's of each parent on clicking on particular parent. This is similar to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055635/jquery-loop-through-dynamic-elements-and-get-data-value)

I am unable to get the required `alert` can some one let me know what is wrong

```js
$(".chapter").on("click", function() {
  let id = $(this).attr("href");
  list = $.map($(id).find(".sportlist"), function(item) {
    alert($(item).data("value"))
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="tree-ehex col-md-3" style="padding-left:0px;float: left; width:215px;overflow-x:scroll;height:261px;" id="treeOrderDiv">
  <ul style="padding-left: 0px;" id="leftsubMenus-Ul">
    <li class="parent_li">
      <span style="font-family: serif;font-size: small;" title="Collapse this branch"><i class="tree-ehex-title glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i></span>
      <a href="#Parent" class='chapter'> Parent</a>
      <ul id='#Parent'>
        <li style="display: list-item;" data-value='20'>
          <a href="#"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;color:black;font-size: smaller;font-family: sans-serif"> Child1 </span></a>
        </li>
        <li style="display: list-item;" data-value='22'>
          <a href="#"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;color:black;font-size: smaller;font-family: sans-serif"> Child2 </span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent_li">
      <span style="font-family: serif;font-size: small;" title="Collapse this branch"><i class="tree-ehex-title glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i></span>
      <a href="#Parent1" class='chapter'> Parent1</a>
      <ul id="#Parent1">
        <li class='sportlist' style="display: list-item;" data-value='22'>
          <a href="#"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;color:black;font-size: smaller;font-family: sans-serif"> Child</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class='sportlist' style="display: list-item;" data-value='24'>
          <a href="#"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;color:black;font-size: smaller;font-family: sans-serif"> Child1 </span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#Parent1")` won't find `<ul id='#Parent1'>` `#` means `id=` so you would want `<ul id="Parent1">` or `$("#\#Parent1")`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here.

- The `#` prefix should not be placed in the `id` attribute in your HTML. Remove it.
- The first group of elements under `#Parent` is missing the `.sportlist` class.

In addition you should note that `map()` or `$.map()` is used to create an array from the jQuery object. If all you want is a loop just use `each()`.

Also don't use inline `style` attributes unless there is no other choice. The best practice is to use CSS styling rules in an external stylesheet.

Finally, don't use `alert()` for debugging as it coerces data types. `console.log()` or `console.dir()` is always the best course of action here.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(".chapter").on("click", function() {
  let selector = $(this).attr("href");

  $(selector).find(".sportlist").each(function() {
    let value = $(this).data('value');
    console.log(value);

    // do something useful with value...
  })
});
```

```css
#treeOrderDiv {
  padding-left: 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 215px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 261px;
}

#leftsubMenus-Ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.parent_li span {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: small;
}

.sportlist {
  display: list-item;
}

.sportlist span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-size: smaller;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="tree-ehex col-md-3" id="treeOrderDiv">
  <ul id="leftsubMenus-Ul">
    <li class="parent_li">
      <span title="Collapse this branch"><i class="tree-ehex-title glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i></span>
      <a href="#Parent" class="chapter">Parent</a>
      <ul id="Parent">
        <li class="sportlist" data-value="20">
          <a href="#"><span>Child1</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="sportlist" data-value="22">
          <a href="#"><span>Child2</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent_li">
      <span title="Collapse this branch"><i class="tree-ehex-title glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></i></span>
      <a href="#Parent1" class="chapter">Parent1</a>
      <ul id="Parent1">
        <li class="sportlist" data-value="22">
          <a href="#"><span>Child</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="sportlist" data-value="24">
          <a href="#"><span>Child1</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*Update*

> If I give href as `#` instead of `#Parent` can we get the list as we are getting currently?

Sure. To do that you need to use DOM traversal instead of directly targeting the elements. Try this:

```
$(".chapter").on("click", function() {
  let $ul = $(this).next('ul');
  $ul.find(".sportlist").each(function() {
    let value = $(this).data('value');
    console.log(value);

    // do something useful with value...
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks I over looked few things

Comment: Hi with href # can we handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the href if `#` you can't use it to target any elements

Comment: I mean I will give href as # instead if Parent can we get the list as we are getting currently

Comment: Or any alternate way for this

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean now. I updated the answer to show you how you can do that

Answer (score 1):

You have number of options:

1. change `id` attrs of `ul` from `<ul id="#Parent">` to `<ul id="Parent">` and leave js as-is
2. or leave html as-is, but change js:

```
$(".chapter").on("click", function() {
 let id = $(this).attr("href");
 let chapter = $(document.getElementById(id));
 list = $.map(chapter.find(".sportlist"), function(item) {
   alert($(item).data("value"))
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to include the `#` in your `id` attributes.  So, change `id='#Parent'` to `id='Parent'`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue without changing the `HTML` by using the following `script`:-

```
$(".chapter").on("click", function() {  
  $.each($(this).next().find('li'), function(){
    alert($(this).data('value'))
  });
});
```